# Play framework + scala: Process checkbox list and selected items

Tags: scala, checkbox, playframework, mapping, helper

I have a list of items I want to show as checkboxes, and I have a list of the items the user actually has selected previously and that I have stored in the database. So what I need is to show all the items but only mark as checked the selected items:

- [ ]item1
- [ ]item2
- [x]item3
- [x]item4

Here is my mapping:

```
def formMapping: Mapping[Data] = {
        mapping(
            "selectedItems" -> play.api.data.Forms.list(String)
        )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
    }
```

And my html:

```
@(theForm: Form[DataForView])

@for((itemValue, itemName) <- allItems) {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@itemValue"/>@itemName<br/>
    }
```

I'm using the name "selectedItems" so it maps to the form field. I though about using the @checkbox helper but then I would only see the selectedItems, not **all** items.

I've considered other options, for instance, eliminating "selectedItems" and having a list of all items with a Boolean that indicates if it is selected or not. But that means that I would have to cross the items with the selectedItems and I was hoping there would be a better way.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've tried this approach:

```
@for(item <- allItems) {
    @if(theForm("selected").contains(@item.value)) {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="@item.value" CHECKED/>@item.name<br/>
    } else {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selected" value="@item.value"/>@item.name<br/>
    }
}
```

But theForm("selected") is something like selected[0], selected[1], ... I can't match it to the form field, which is a list of Strings.

Answer (score 2):

of the top of my head you could do something like this:

```
@(theForm: Form[DataForView], selectedItems: Set[String])

@for((itemValue, itemName) <- allItems) {
    @if(selectedItems.contains(@itemValue)) {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@itemValue" CHECKED/>@itemName<br/>
    } else {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems" value="@itemValue"/>@itemName<br/>
    }
}
```

Where the selectedItems is the set of selected elements.

Comment: I've been trying something  like that, since I can't find another way. The thing is, I think selectedItems should be part of the form, right? It's part of the data I'm trying to update. Please see the update for more details.